# Conditional container for vue-router named view?

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router

Is it possible to detect whether a named view is set in the router view parent component (i.e. the one containing the `<router-view name='...'>` tag)?

Use case: I have a navigation-drawer who's content that varies depending on route, but the prepend and append drawer slot content is always the same. But for some pages there is no nav-drawer content and in such cases I don't want to render the nav-drawer at all. For example, the component template looks like:

```
<template>
  <system-bar></system-bar>
  <v-navigation-drawer
    v-bind='navDrawerProps'
  >
    <template v-slot:prepend>
      <v-list-item @click='rail = !rail' prepend-icon="mdi-menu"></v-list-item>
      <v-divider></v-divider>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:append>
      <v-divider></v-divider>
      <v-list-item>
        <template v-if='model.connection?.token'>
          <router-link  to='/logout'><v-list-item prepend-icon="mdi-logout-variant">Logout</v-list-item></router-link>
        </template>
        <template v-else>
          <v-list-item prepend-icon="mdi-login-variant" @click='login'>Login / Signup</v-list-item>
        </template>
      </v-list-item>
    </template>
    <router-view name="nav"></router-view>
  </v-navigation-drawer>
  <v-main app>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </v-main>
</template>
```

I want a `v-if` condition for the `v-navigation-drawer` like `v-if=named-view-called-nav-is-defined`.

Comment: Where is your `named-view-called-nav-is-defined`? I mean in parent component or in App.vue?

Comment: I believe that you can simply define some flag in the `meta` object of your routes which should not have a `nav-drawer` and then use `v-if` to check for the absense of that flag in the current route.

Comment: @Duannx named-views are named in the router routes -- https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-views.html

Comment: @IVOGELOV yeah I could do that I guess, but want to merely test for the existence of the named router from the component to avoid duplicate fragile code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution. Figured out you can access named routes from `$route.matched`. Given that I defined a computed prop to use in `v-if`:

```
  computed: {
    hasNav() {
      const components = this.$route.matched
        .map((m: any) => m.components)
        .reduce((a: any, b: any) => ({ ...a, ...b }), {});
      return 'nav' in components;
    }
  },
```